# UITableView indexPathForSelectedRow always return 0 in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I need to get the Index Of `UITableView` with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in iOS.

First i added `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and retrieve the index Path of Selected row with following codes.

```
- (void)handleLongPress : (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)ges
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblMainTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.row);
}
```

When i tapping on third row of `UITableView` , it only return `0` and always return `0` wherever i tap on tableView.

How can i get the index tableview with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`?

Thanks for any suggestions and help.

Comment: is your tblMainTableView IBOutlet hooked up?  If it's nil then that's why you're always getting 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)ges
{
    CGPoint touch = [ges locationInView:self.tblMainTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblMainTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touch];

}
```

Use the touch point on the tableView to access the row via the `indexPathForRowAtPoint` method

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your row is not getting selected because you're not "touching up" until after the long press–it would probably work if you tapped it and then pressed, but that defeats the purpose. You can use this to get the point of the long press:

```
CGPoint pressPoint = [ges locationInView];
```

Then get the cell at that point with this:

```
indexPath path = [self.tblMainTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pressPoint];
```